# Selenium How to access nested elements (css BootStrap)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Guys I have a web page designed in bootstrap and would like to access the elements of my drop down and also be able to click into the elemnets to the next page I have been using the Firefox Selenium IDE to get the xpath which when I validate it the path exist .I get true but When I try to get the click I get an error

```
    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
```

here is my code and I would like to get to the drop down and click on the links available any help appreciated

```
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-left" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle  hidden-xs" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicons glyphicons-bed-alt"></i> Management<span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li class="  hidden-xs">
                                <a href="/Occupancy" onclick="clearStorage(); return true;"><span><i class="glyphicons glyphicons-bed-alt"></i> Occupancy</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="  hidden-xs">
                                <a href="/List"><span><i class="glyphicons glyphicons-bed-alt"></i> Ward Occupancy</span></a>
                            </li>


                        </ul>
                    </li>


                </ul>

            </div>
```

I would like to be able to look for the  management element and then get to the click on the drop down thanks in advance

Comment: Try with xpath.   //*[@id='navbar-collapse']//a[contains(@href,'/List')

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing around and I finally got my answer from http://learn-automation.com/handle-bootstrap-dropdown-in-selenium-webdriver/   .With bootstrap drop down you need to get to the element click open the element and then click the links on it

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Management')]")).click();

    Thread.sleep(2000);

       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='navbar-collapse']/ul/li/ul/li/a/span")).click();
```